# Main domain with codeigniter, subdomain without codeigniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have uploaded a CodeIgniter site to `public_html` folder on server, which works properly.

http://my-site-name-here.com

Now, I have created a subdomain "`sub`" for which there is a directory in `public_html` named "`sub`". I have uploaded a non-CodeIgniter application in that folder.
If I try to go to http://sub.my-site-name-here.com, it gives me "`500 Internal server error`".
And if I try to go to http://my-site-name-here.com/sub, it gives me CodeIgniter response for page not found.

How can I set subdomain that does not use CodeIgniter?

**UPDATE:**

I am trying different htaccess rewrites. Current .htaccess content is:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|img/current|css/current|js/current|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?spiders\.haitspirit\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/spiders
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /spiders/$1 [L]
```

**UPDATE 2:**

I have also moved all CodeIgniter directories and files (except index.php) into a directory called "`main`" and edited `index.php` accordingly. Still main site works, subdomain doesnt.

**UPDATE 3:**

I tried same thing in `localhost` and now able to get server error logs. Error shows **it has reached maximum redirect loops.**

Comment: I would advice you to look at your logs and find out what the 500 internal server error is about.

Comment: you have to create subdomain in cpanel, is it done?

Comment: @Mischa I am not able to see server error logs. My host provider / control panel has no option for that. Though I have generated a support ticket for that but still no reply from their side.

Comment: yes @Maulikpatel, I have created subdomain using cpanel and it created a directory for that subdomain automatically.

Comment: can u paste ur htaccess contents? Have u disabled the rewrite condition rule for ur sub-domain folder??

Comment: @AmitHorakeri, I have pasted current .htaccess content in question. Is anything wrong in content..?

Comment: wats the name of the subdomain that u ve created?

Comment: @AmitHorakeri, it is "spiders"

Comment: did u fix this issue or is it stil der?

Comment: Hi @AmitHorakeri, till now I was trying.. it is solved just now :).. putting as answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution. Pasting here. It may help others who are using CodeIgniter package as main domain and non-CodeIgniter package as sub-domain and having trouble redirecting.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/sub/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/errors/page_missing [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.sitename\.com$
RewriteCond $1 !^sub/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /sub/$1 [L]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|img|css|js|robots\.txt|sub)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

where `sub` is the name of sub-domain (assuming same name is used for directory too) and `sitename` is the name of your domain.

If anyone tries to go to `http://sitename.com/sub` then it will display `404 Not found` page from CodeIgniter.

Hope this helps..